# enumerate through a list or dict every x seconds with timer or dispatchertimer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, dispatchertimer

say i have a dictionary with 3 value/key pairs.

```
private void someMethod()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    d.Add("cat", 22);
    d.Add("dog", 14);
    d.Add("llama", 2);
    d.Add("iguana", 6);

    somesortoftimercode
}

private void DisplayText(string x, int y)
{
    label1.Text = x;
    int someValue= 3+y;
}
```

i want iterate through this dictionary, i want a dispatchertimer(or timer) to call displayText with the dictionary values every 3 seconds.  how do i do that?

UPDATE:

i can't use Thread.Sleep(XXX), i can't block the thread.  i have other stuff going in the background, and i can't spin this out to have threads all over the place.

plus:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
private Timer timer;

private void someMethod()
{
    var d = new Dictionary<string, int>
                {
                    {"cat", 22}, 
                    {"dog", 14}, 
                    {"llama", 2}, 
                    {"iguana", 6}
                };

    int index = 0;
    TimerCallback timerCallBack = state =>
                                        {
                                            DisplayText(d.ElementAt(index).Key, d.ElementAt(index).Value);
                                            if(++index == d.Count)
                                            {
                                                index = 0;
                                            }
                                        };
    timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}

private void DisplayText(string x, int y)
{
    label1.Text = x;
    int someValue= 3+y;
}
```

If you need enumerate dictionary only once you may use following code:

```
new Task(() =>
    {
        d.All(kvp =>
        {
            DisplayText(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return true;
        });
    }
).Start();
```

Comment: You may block another thread not the main. I've update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of the timers provided by the framework such as

```
System.Threading.Timers.Timer
```

Set the interval to whatever you want and then in the Tick event call a `foreach` loop that iterates over your collection. Per your example

```
foreach(var pair in d)
{ 
   DisplayText(pair.key, pair.value);
}
```

Comment: You might save a few milliseconds by doing `foreach (var kvp in d) { DisplayText(kvp.Key, kvp.Value); }`, to avoid looking up the values each time.

Comment: @JoeEnos and it's actually more correct if there are multiple values for a key, changing my answer.

Comment: not, this doesn't work for me.  the foreach loop will go over every single one at once, not one at a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form with a label named `labell` on it and try this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someMethod();
    }

    Thread thread;
    private void someMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        d.Add("cat", 22);
        d.Add("dog", 14);
        d.Add("llama", 2);
        d.Add("iguana", 6);

        thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Do));
        thread.Start(d);
    }

    delegate void _DisplayText(string x, int y);
    private void DisplayText(string x, int y)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new _DisplayText(DisplayText), x, y);
            return;
        }
        label1.Text = x;
        int someValue = 3 + y;
    }

    public void Do(object dic)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> d = (Dictionary<string, int>)dic;
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var item in d)
            {
                DisplayText(item.Key, item.Value);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, this cannot be done with thread.sleep.  i cannot have it block while it waits

Comment: Note that it does not block while it wait because I created another thread.

Comment: If you try this sample code, you will see that you can still interact with the GUI of the program, while another thread causes the label to change every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction. I assume you are creating a Win Forms application. If not, this won't work for you.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cat", 22},
        {"dog", 14},
        {"llama", 2},
        {"iguana", 6}
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
        foreach (var item in d)
        {
            label1.Text = item.Key;
            int someValue = 3 + item.Value;
        }
        t.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) (from the Microsoft Cloud Team) has a very nice way to do what you want.

After adding references to Rx (which you can do via NuGet) you just drop this into your `someMethod` method:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0))
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        d.ToArray() // Helps to prevent race conditions
            .ForEach(kvp => DisplayText(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    });
```

It sets up the timer - which fires on a background thread - and then marshals the call to the dispatcher (i.e. UI thread) to prevent cross-thread issues.

If you're using Windows Forms then the `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` becomes `.ObserveOn(label1)` or `.ObserveOn(form)` and you're good to go.

No need to muck about with explicitly creating threads, timers or background workers.

Here are the links for Rx:

- [Reactive Extensions Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads)
- [Reactive Extensions (Rx) v1.0.10621](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26649)